# Excel 2010 - VLookup -

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function, vlookup

I have two identities associated with one unique value in the table. I need to pull both the values in another sheet using vlookup - is that possible.

Here is the example:

```
Id  Owner Name
A1  Owner 1
A1  Owner 2
B1  Owner 3
B1  Owner 4
C1  Owner 5
C1  Owner 6
D1  Owner 7
D1  Owner 8
```

Here we have one unique id (eg: A1) associated with two Owners (Owner 1 and 2), I need this to be pulled in another sheet in the following format

```
Id  1st Owner Name  2nd Owner Name
A1      
B1      
C1      
D1
```

Comment: Is that **always** the pattern?

Answer (score 1):

So, with your data, my sheet looks like this -

[image]

So I want to list the owners in columns C:D, referencing whatever is in column A.

In C13

```
=INDEX($B$2:$B$9, SMALL(IF($A13=$A$2:$A$9, ROW($A$2:$A$9)-ROW($A$2)+1), ROW($1:$1)))
```

In D13

```
=INDEX($B$2:$B$9, SMALL(IF($A13=$A$2:$A$9, ROW($A$2:$A$9)-ROW($A$2)+1), ROW($2:$2)))
```

These are **array formulas**. Type them and press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> <kbd>SHFT</kbd> <kbd>ENTR</kbd> - they will get curly brackets. 
Drag down the column, as I did in the example.

You can change the `Row($1:$1)` to `$2:$2` if you expect two results, `$3:$3` for three and so on. If you don't use the absolute reference for this, it will change as you drag.